# Git repository amazon ec2

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, putty

Hello I'm following this one tutorial with my AWS EC2 Instance with Ubuntu Server:
http://codecrunchero.blogspot.com/2012/06/setting-up-remote-git-repository-on.html

And I'm stuck on the first step:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@amazonpublicdns.com
```

Getting this error:

> Warning: Identity file mykey.pem not accessible: No such file or
>   directory The authenticity of host 'amazonpublicdns.com' can't be established.

I'm using putty on windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in your own credentials. Like

```
ssh -i ** MY .PEM LOCATION ** ec2-user@**MY IP**
```

A more useful example:

```
ssh -i C:\my.pem ec2-user@mywebsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ssh command line but you are using Putty.
You need to use Putty GUI to enter the IP address of your instance.

Now the tricky part is that Putty does not understand pem format and using ppk format instead :(

There is a simple utility called puttygen that will transform a pem file to ppk.

After converting - use this ppk file in Putty ->ssh>auth and connect to your instance.